# Why my code showing pragma error on remix?

Tags: compiler-errors, ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm practicing with some open codes. also I'm pretty new on solidity. When i try to compile my code, it keep getting this Error: **browser/grow.sol:1:1: Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version! Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.5.0;" ^** . I'm using REMIX & compiler version 0.5.0

```
    /**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2020-08-25
*/

pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() 
        public 
        view 
        returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) 
        public 
        view 
        returns (uint balance);
    
    function allowance
        (address tokenOwner, address spender) 
        public 
        view 
        returns (uint remaining);

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens)              public 
        returns (bool success);
    
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens)      public 
        returns (bool success);

    function transferFrom 
        (address from, address to, uint tokens)                 public 
        returns (bool success);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    
    
}

contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); c = a - b; } function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { c = a * b; require(a == 0 || c / a == b); } function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}


contract MYTOKEN is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; 
    
    uint256 public _totalSupply;
    
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    constructor() public {
        name = "MYTOKEN";
        symbol = "MYT";
        decimals = 18;
        
        _totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;
        
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }
    
    
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply - balances[address(0)];
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
        
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No errors on my side. Have you tried to recompile your code once you've haded the `pragma` statement? In remix, you can recompile your code in the `SOLIDITY COMPILER` section (left side of the screen). Sometimes error stays until code is recompiled.